# How to specify to grepl to take into account a vowel irrespective of the accent

Tags: r, grepl

I am working on data where the words are in French.
I want grepl to take into account the word, whether the vowel has an accent or not.
Here is a part of code:

Here I want grepl to spot all word that are `radiothérapie` or `radiotherapie`, that is to ignore the accent

```
ifelse(grepl("Radiothe(é)rapie",mydata$word),"yes","no")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ifelse(grepl("Radioth[eé]rapie", c("Radiotherapie", "Radiothérapie", "Radio")),"yes","no")
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the brute force way of doing this would be to use a character class containing all variations of the letter, e.g.

```r
ifelse(grepl("Radioth[eé]rapie", mydata$word), "yes", "no")
```

Comment: It is great thank you

Answer (score 1):

possible solution: convert to `Latin-ASCII` before using `grepl`.

```
x <- c("radiothérapie", "radiotherapie")
grepl("radiotherapie", stringi::stri_trans_general(x,"Latin-ASCII"))
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

this should work for most (all?) accents..

Answer (score 1):

You can take a more universal approach

```
string = "ábçdêfgàõp"
iconv(string, to='ASCII//TRANSLIT')
# [1] "abcdefgaop"
```

**For your scenario**

```
x <- "Radiotherapie"
y <- c("Radiotherapie", "Radiothérapie", "Radio")

grepl(iconv(x, to='ASCII//TRANSLIT'), iconv(y, to='ASCII//TRANSLIT'))

# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trick using `grepl` with `regex`:

Use caret inside the group which negates your selection:

```
x <- c("radiothérapie", "radiotherapie")

grepl('radioth[é^e]rapie', x)
```

```
[1] TRUE TRUE
```